# Create Excel 2019 heatmap from data in another tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula, heatmap

I have an Excel file with rates in one tab and companies in the other. The rates are easily heatmapped with conditional formatting in their tab. What I need to do is transfer that to the tab with company names so their background color aligns with the heatmap on the rates tab. Any suggestions? Is there a formula I can use for this?

Comment: Conditional formatting will not allow the use of gradient coloring using numbers from a different sheet.  You will probably need to use vba.

Comment: Do you have an example of doing this with VBA? Always tricky to use corporately due to security

Comment: Apply the heatmap on the numbers, loop over those cells and inspect their `.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`, and then apply that color to the cells with company names using `.Interior.Color` maybe